# Monoid homomorphisms to the additive naturals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, monoid

Part of something I'm doing research in requires monoid homomorphisms $(\omega\times\omega,+,\bar{0})\to(\omega,+,0)$.  (I'm just using component-wise addition for the product monoid).  Are there any homomorphisms that aren't of the form $(n,m)\mapsto kn+lm$ (or $kn-lm$, or $lm-kn$) for $k,l\in\omega$?  Google isn't being very friendly with this question.  I'll obviously take any duplicate questions too, if there are any.  Thank you!

Comment: If $k,l,m,n \in \omega$ and the operation on $\omega$ is $+$, then what does the multiplication in $kn+lm$ mean? Do you mean $k,l \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: If $\omega$ is the monoid of natural numbers under addition, then it's really easy to show that the monoid homomorphisms $\omega\times\omega\to\omega$ are the maps $(x,y)\mapsto ax+by$, where $a$ and $b$ can be chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: Does $\omega$ necessarily mean the natrual numbers with addion? I understood it as denoting an arbitrary abelian monoid.

Answer (score 1):

Even in the special case of abelian groups this is not true. Take for example $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with the usual addition and
$$
 \mathbb{Z}^2 \times \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}^2, \quad
 ((k,l),(n,m)) \mapsto (k+l,n+m).
$$

PS: In case you don’t mean an arbitrary abelian monoid $(\omega,+,0)$ but the natural numbers with addition, then the statement holds: If $f \colon \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is an monoid homomorphism with $f((1,0)) = k$ and $f((0,1)) = l$ then
$$
 f((n,m))
 = f(n \cdot (1,0)+ m \cdot (0,1))
 = n \cdot f((1,0)) + m \cdot f((0,1))
 = kn + lm.
$$
(We just use that $\mathbb{N}^2$ is the free abelian monoid on $2$ generators.)
Here we use the notation that for an abelian monoid $(M,+,0)$, an element $x \in M$ and a natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we abreviate $n \cdot x = \sum_{i=1}^n x$.